# How to write this integral in a nice way?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I have a  function $f(a,b):= \int_{-1}^{1} e^{i (ax+bx^2)}dx$  with $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ and now I want to find out what $|f(a,b)|^2$ is. Is there a way to write this in a nice way? Cause always when I try to do this, I have the feeling that I am missing numerous symmetries here.

Comment: Without specific values of $a,b$, it's hard to know what symmetries or cancellations you might be able to exploit.  Writing out the integrand of $f$ in terms of real and imaginary parts (cosine and sine) seems a good first step.

Comment: alright, we have $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Did you try $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1e^{i(ax-ay+bx^2-by^2)}dxdy$ then change variables to $x+y$ and $x-y$?

Comment: @Michael sounds to be a good idea. do you want to post it as an answer (and give a few details if you want to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square modulus of $f(a,b)$, is given by:
$$\frac{\pi}{2|b|}\left(\left(\text{C}\left[\frac{a-2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]-\text{C}\left[\frac{a+2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]\right)^2+\left(\text{S}\left[\frac{a-2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]-\text{S}\left[\frac{a+2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]\right)^2\right)$$
where:
$$\text{C}(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\cos\frac{\pi t^2}{2}\,dt,\quad \text{S}(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\sin\frac{\pi t^2}{2}\,dt$$
are both bounded functions on the real line:
$$\max(|C(z)|,|S(z)|)\leq C(1) <\frac{4}{5}.$$

Comment: Did you do this using a CAS?-and do you know what happens in the case of $b <0$?

Comment: You get this just by considering the real and imaginary part of $e^{i(at+bt^2)}$ and using simple changes of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $$|f(a,b)|^2=f(a,b)f(-a,-b)=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1e^{i(ax−ay+bx^2−by^2)}dxdy$$ and then change variables to $x+y$ and $x−y$?
$u=x+y,v=x-y,dudv=2dxdy$, $$\frac12\left[\int_{-2}^0du\int_{-2-u}^{2+u}dv+\int_0^2du\int_{u-2}^{2-u}dv\right]e^{i(av+buv)}$$, but then I agree it gets ugly.

Comment: if you think about it, then this does not really simplify the problem, it makes it even more difficult I think. so I just want to wait, if somebody else comes up with a nice idea.