# Maxima of the function $\left \vert \int_{-1}^1 e^{i(ax+bx^2)}dx \right \vert$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image: As you can see the local maxima should have some periodic distribution]

I am looking for extrema of the function

$$g(a,b):=\left \vert \int_{-1}^1 e^{i(ax+bx^2)}dx \right \vert$$
where $a,b >0$  are real parameters. I already plotted this function and got the impression that there are periodically local extrema along some particular curve, but it was hard to be more precise. My question is: Can we say anything about extrema from the function itself analytically?

In particular, I am interested in the asymptotic distribution of the maxima (if we cannot catch them analytically) for $a,b>0$ that you can see in the plot above. Apparently, they start with "more or less" $a = b$, but how are they distributed for large $a,b$? They also seem to have some periodicity, can we say anything about this?

You might also want to look at the new representations given in the comments :-)

If anything is unclear about this, please let me know.

NOTICE: Anything( also periodicity etc.) you could say about the extrema is probably useful, so I deliberately want this question to be somewhat broad.

Comment: I think it is worth to link the original question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942841/how-to-write-this-integral-in-a-nice-way/942893#942893 and state that you are looking for stationary points of the square modulus of $$f(a,b)=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{i(ax+bx^2)}\,dx.$$

Comment: Maple produces $$ 1/2\,\sqrt {\pi }{{\rm e}^{1/4\,\Im \left( {\frac {{a}^{2}}{b}}
 \right) }} \left| {\frac {1}{\sqrt {-ib}} \left( -{\it Erf} \left( {
\frac {i/2 \left( a-2\,b \right) }{\sqrt {-ib}}} \right) +{\it Erf}
 \left( {\frac {i/2 \left( a+2\,b \right) }{\sqrt {-ib}}} \right) 
 \right) } \right| 
 $$ for $g(a,b)$.

Comment: I suspect that I is the imaginary part, so this exponent in front of the absolute value vanishes, as both a and b are real, but thank you :-), I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Another nice representation is due to Jack D'Aurizio in the thread he linked: The square modulus of $f(a,b)$, is given by:
$$\frac{\pi}{2|b|}\left(\left(\text{C}\left[\frac{a-2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]-\text{C}\left[\frac{a+2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]\right)^2+\left(\text{S}\left[\frac{a-2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]-\text{S}\left[\frac{a+2 |b|}{\sqrt{2|b| \pi }}\right]\right)^2\right)$$
where:
$$\text{C}(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\cos\frac{\pi t^2}{2}\,dt,\quad \text{S}(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\sin\frac{\pi t^2}{2}\,dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a plot of $|f(a,b)|$ where $f(a,b)=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{i(ax+bx^2)}\,dx$:

[image]

Moreover, we have (we can assume $a,b\geq 0$ since $f$ is an even function with respect to both its arguments):
$$|f(a,b)|=2\left|\int_{0}^{1+a/(2b)}e^{ibx^2}\,dx\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\left|\int_{0}^{a+b+\frac{a^2}{4b}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{-iu}\,du\right|.$$

By assuming $c\triangleq a+b+\frac{a^2}{4b}\geq\pi$, we can exploit the periodicity of the complex exponential function, $e^{i(u+\pi)}=-e^{iu}$, in order to have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}2\int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du+\int_{\pi}^{c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du\\&+&\int_{0}^{c-\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du+\int_{c-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the two middle terms in the RHS almost cancel out, leaving:
$$\left|\int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}e^{iu}\,du\right|\leq K_1+\frac{K_2}{\sqrt{c-\pi}}.$$
Hence it is expected that $f(a,b)$, far enough from the origin, goes to zero like:

> $$|f(a,b)|\ll \frac{1}{|b+a/2|}.$$

Comment: the question was where we have extrema. I agree that looking at |f(a,b)| is easier than |f(a,b)|². But this seems to be about answer how this function behaves asymptotically, which is somewhat different.

Comment: @TobiasHurth: to localize the stationary points with accuracy looks quite difficult to me, are you sure you really need them, instead of a good asymptotics?

Comment: well, what I am interested in is the following: You see in your plot that for $a,b \ge 0$ you seem to get periodically local maxima that seem to lie almost along the diagonal. The question is, how these maxima are distributed asymptotically. Are they really distributed along the diagonal (so $a = b$) or rather quadratic and so on....

Comment: @TobiasHurth: Given $g(a,b)$ and my asymptotics, I would bet that the "principal stationary points" (there many of them) occur when $a=\pm 2b$. Are you looking for a proof of the following fact: given a compact subset $K$ of ${\mathbb{R}^+}^2$, the maximum of $|f(a,b)|$ over $K$ occurs when $a=2b$?

Comment: if you can do it, then this would totally answer my question, although I'd say that this can be only asymptotitcally true, cause if you look at your plot, then I'd say that for small $a,b$ the relationship seems to be much closer to $a=b$. I should add that I would also award a bounty afterwards to your answer, if you are able to say something nice about the distribution of the maxima.